# Unusual behaviour of findall

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

The following looks very unusual :

```
?- findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), X).
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

The trace even more so

```
?- trace, findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), X).
^  Call: (11) findall(_100058, member(_100058, [1, 2, 3]), _100058) ? creep
^  Exit: (11) findall([1, 2, 3], user:member([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
X = [1, 2, 3]
```

Thinking in terms of semantics of `findall` this makes little sense. What is going on?

Comment: Good find. In particular `findall([1,2,3],member([1,2,3],[1,2,3]),[1,2,3]).` fails. The above makes only sense if the variant `X` and the bag `X` are not the same `X` although the trace indicates otherwise. Breakage due to the imperative program underneath. This probably warrants a fix (if it doesn't involve expensive checks)

Comment: Ad edit: this does not depend on the specific implementation. It is like that everywhere, and also in the standard.

Comment: @false : ISO standard says that this behavior is normal? Is this not a quirk of implementing `findall` in a specific way?

Comment: @rajashekar: yes it does. And I have not seen any other interpretation of this highly procedural built-in anywhere anytime. Remember the pure part of Prolog is based on first order logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on my comments, maybe this might help:

```
?- findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

If you look closely, you will see that Prolog (SWI, in this case) did not print a substitution for `X`. This means that `X` is not bound when the query succeeds. Indeed:

```
?- findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs), var(X).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

This does not mean that `X` is *never* bound *while* the query executes:

```
?- findall(X, ( member(X, [1, 2, 3]), writeln(X) ), Xs), var(X).
1
2
3
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

But after all solutions have been generated, `X` is unbound and can be bound to some other value -- such as the list of solutions. This will work in any standard conforming Prolog, as the standard says explicitly that `findall` only tries to unify its third argument after it has created the list of solutions. It even contains an example with sharing between the template and the list of instantiations:

```
findall(X, (X=1;X=2), [X, Y]).
   Succeeds, unifying X with 1, and Y with 2.
```

So how does this binding and unbinding work? With a failure-driven loop, as quoted in rajashekar's answer from the SWI-Prolog implementation. In general, succeeding predicates bind some variables. When at some later point something fails (or, equivalently, the user presses <kbd>;</kbd> when prompted by the toplevel), backtracking takes place: It unbinds variables to allow them to take new values, then retries some goal.

What goes on inside `findall` is the same as goes on when you write the following:

```
?- ( member(X, [1, 2, 3]), writeln(X), false ; true ), var(X).
1
2
3
true.
```

So while `findall` is very impure, it is not *so* impure as to be completely un-Prolog-like. In fact, we can write our own:

```
:- dynamic my_findall_bag/1.

my_findall(Template, Goal, Instances) :-
    % initialization
    retractall(my_findall_bag(_)),
    asserta(my_findall_bag([])),
    
    % collect solutions
    (   call(Goal),
        copy_term(Template, NewSolution),
        retract(my_findall_bag(PreviousSolutions)),
        asserta(my_findall_bag([NewSolution | PreviousSolutions])),
        % failure-driven loop: after saving the solution, force Goal to
        % generate a new one
        false
    ;   true ),

    % cleanup and finish; the saved solutions are in reversed order (newest
    % first), so reverse them
    retract(my_findall_bag(AllSavedSolutions)),
    reverse(AllSavedSolutions, Instances).
```

This behaves as expected:

```
?- my_findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

Or even:

```
?- my_findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), X).
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

A minor problem with this is that the instantiation of `Goal` should be checked. A *major* problem with this is that all `my_findall` calls share the same bag, so calling `my_findall` from inside a `my_findall` (or in parallel) will make you unhappy. This could be fixed using some sort of `gensym` mechanism to give each `my_findall` run its unique key into the database.

As for the trace output, it is an unfortunate consequence of wanting to express "your goal succeeded with such-and-such bindings" on one line. At the point of success, it *is* true that `findall(X, ..., X)` succeeded, and it *is* true that `X = [1, 2, 3]`, and hence it *is* true that the successful instance of the goal is `findall([1, 2, 3], ..., [1, 2, 3])`.

Consider:

```
forty_two(FortyTwo) :-
    var(FortyTwo),
    FortyTwo = 42.

my_call(Goal) :-
    format('about to call ~w~n', [Goal]),
    call(Goal),
    format('success: ~w~n', [Goal]).
```

For example:

```
?- my_call(forty_two(X)).
about to call forty_two(_2320)
success: forty_two(42)
X = 42.
```

So `forty_two(42)` is a succeeding instance of `forty_two(X)`. Even though `forty_two(42)` does *not* succeed:

```
?- forty_two(42).
false.
```

It is *logical* that printing the term `forty_two(X)` in an environment with `X = 42` prints `forty_two(42)`. I think the problem is that this *logical* behavior sticks out as strange among all the *non-logical* stuff going on here.

Comment: Thank you for a prolog implementation of `findall` it was illuminating.

Comment: copy_term/2 is redundant asserta/1 will do a copy for you. And therefore you already see the problem of the algorithm, its quadratic. Also there could be problems with findall/3 inside findall/3.

Comment: The problem with `findall` inside `findall` is mentioned in the answer as a major problem. You're right about the extra copy (and `retract` will do one more, no?). The implementation is meant to be short and illustrative and has served that purpose. The quadratic behavior is from using a list, one could do it linearly by `assertz`ing each answer, then collecting those into a list. That's slightly more code.

Answer (score 1):

I did some code diving to try and figure out what is going on. In swi-prolog `listing(findall, [source(true)]).` gives the following code :

```
findall(Templ, Goal, List) :-
    findall(Templ, Goal, List, []).

findall(Templ, Goal, List, Tail) :-
    setup_call_cleanup(
        '$new_findall_bag',
        findall_loop(Templ, Goal, List, Tail),
        '$destroy_findall_bag').
```

`findall_loop` in the appropriate file is as follows :

```
findall_loop(Templ, Goal, List, Tail) :-
    (   Goal,
        '$add_findall_bag'(Templ)   % fails
    ;   '$collect_findall_bag'(List, Tail)
    ).
```

After consulting the C source files, I found out that `findall/4` is setting up a global variable in C-source (`'$new_findall_bag'`) and `findall_loop/4` is pushing the `Templ` to it when the `Goal` succeeds (with `'$add_findall_bag'(Templ)`). When the `Goal` fails `Templ` is uninstantiated and hence the final clause `'$collect_findall_bag'(List, Tail)` succeeds even when `List` and `Templ` are the same variable.

We can see in trace that `Templ` is usuall uninstantiated.

```
?- trace, findall(X, member(X, [1, 2, 3]), Xs).
^  Call: (11) findall(_28906, member(_28906, [1, 2, 3]), _28916) ? creep
^  Exit: (11) findall(_28906, user:member(_28906, [1, 2, 3]), [1, 2, 3]) ? creep
Xs = [1, 2, 3].
```

So the process of finding all instantiations of `Templ` so that the `Goal` succeeds is separate from the process of collecting all those instantiations into the variable `List` and hence we can use the same variable without causing and error. But the semantics of writing such a clause is not making much sense to me.

EDIT: Similar situation occurs in `gprolog`, where the process of collecting solutions and that of retriving them are separate. Relevant `Yap` code also looks quite similar, but i was not able to install it to check.

Comment: I just could not figure out how `findall_loop` is actually looping over all solutions even after trying the C source.

Comment: That loop is not in the C source, it's in the snippet you posted above: `findall_loop` calls `Goal` and adds the answer to the bag. *Then it fails inside `$add_findall_bag`.* This forces it to try `Goal` again, which will generate a new answer, which it adds using `$add_findall_bag`, which then fails again, etc. This is a "normal" failure-driven loop, except that the failure is hidden inside another predicate. Fortunately there is the comment, at least.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie : Thank you, I have been trying to find a loop in `add_finall_bag` function in the source code. Now that I check again, it always returns `FALSE` when used as a unary predicate. This is wonderful.

Comment: BTW this repeated failure is also the reason why you can reuse `X`: Every time the `Goal` succeeds, it will bind `X`. But then the failure will unbind `X` again so that the next alternative for `Goal` can bind it again. If `Goal` terminates, this sequence will always end in a failure of `Goal`, so `X` will not be bound after all solutions have been collected. So it can be bound to something else! Like the result of the `findall`. No, this doesn't make "logical" sense, it's very procedural.

Comment: How do you handle findall/3 inside findall/3 ? Does '$new_findall_bag' use its own thread local stack? Why not some '$new_findall_bag'/1 that returns a reference to the bag?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse : Yes, `'$new_findall_bag'` does use its own stack. Since the reference is not a logical term, i.e., it's value changes and makes the code dynamic, I think it was a design decision to just use them in `C` and not reference them in `prolog`. If you look at @IsabelleNewbie's answer then you can see how `findall` is implemented using dynamic code.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse : `findall` inside `findall` is handled using stack similar to how recursive functions use stack. If if a findall finishes execution then the stack frame(here bag) is freed or else a new one is put on top.