# Swi Prolog: how to count the number of elements by using rules (not query)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

As title stated above, how to make this possible?
For example:

```
**Facts:**
parent(child, parent).

parent(child, parent2).

parent(child2, parent).

parent(child2, parent2).

**Rules:**
childof(X,Y) :- parent(Y, X).  
number_of_child(X,Y):- X has Y number of child
```

How should I implement the number_of_child rules?
My expected answer is Y will show 2 (since there are child and child2) or something like that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about `setof/3`, `bagof/3` and `findall/3`. They are general prolog predicates to find all solutions.

If you want something `swi-prolog` specific just to count the solutions then you can use `aggregate_all`.

```
num_children(X, N) :- aggregate_all(count, child_of(X, _Y), N).
```

https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/SingletonVar.html

Comment: Thank you for giving me some ideas and this successfully meet my expectation. Though, the variables have a little bit problem. For my case it should be
num_children(X, N) :- aggregate_all(count, child_of(X,N), N).  as Y is recognized as unknown variable by the swi prolog program. Thank you again for giving me some ideas.

Comment: @ZonG: No you should use `child_of(X, _Y)` to suppress the warning. While `child_of(X, N)` works it is not an accurate portrayal of what is happening. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining. Can you explain more about why 'child_of(X, N)' is not accurate despite it shows same answer as 'child_of(X, _Y)' does?

Comment: It is a bit complicated. Go through this if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64716106/unusual-behaviour-of-findall