# looking for help in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I want to make function Findall in prolog that same to the built in function the built in function takes:

findall(Object,Constrain,List).

I try so hard in it but I want it without any built-in with my own built but it is so difficult.

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722773/4437190

Comment: Predicate, not function.